Single-mother with two daughters, final scene: sunning and playing in garden, song fitting action, Danish, early 2000
Here is another difficult one I'm afraid.
I'm looking for a Danish movie - not sure if it was originally for cinema or television.  It was aired on Norwegian television (NRK) 10-15 years ago, so I guess it's from 2000-2005.
It's about a single-mother (around 35-40?) and her two young daughters - the youngest 7-9yo, the oldest 9-12yo.
I don't really remember much of it, but I would guess it was a drama or a romantic drama.  And I'd guess there would be about the mother dating some guy or something...
What I do remember, is the final scene; where the mother (alone, no guy) and her daughters are in the garden/backyard.  The mother is sitting in a chair - maybe by a table (and a parasol) - and sunning herself.  The daughters are playing together nearby.  A song starts - obviously made for the movie - sung by a female singer, where the lyrics mirror the action of the final scene as it happens:

Something about the mother and her daughters in the garden...
  "Then Den eldste tøs (the oldest girl) turns towards her
  mother and asks her/says" something...

While on the screen, the oldest girl abandons her play and turns to ask her mother something.
Song continues, and end-credits rolls.
I know this is very vague, but does somebody got any idea what this movie is called in Danish (and perhaps in English) when it's from, and who directed it?
